# TFS 2010 - Unable to create Team Project

Tags: vmware, team-project

I had created a Team Project Collection and added a team project on TFS 2010 which was a created on a VMWare space. Of late my system administrator copied the image of the server and recreated it on to a new VMWare server due to space shortage.

Not sure if the given issue is occuring due to that but post the movement I am getting this error when trying to create a Team Project on TFS 2010

> **Error  TF24023:**
>
> Team Foundation Server Configuration Failure. The New
>   Team Project Wizard work item component could not connect to the Team
>   Foundation Server \
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Contact the administrator for the Team Foundation Server
>   \ to confirm that the
>   server is available on the network. Also, you might find additional
>   helpful information in the project creation log. The log shows each
>   action taken by the wizard at the time of the failure and may include
>   additional details about the error.
>
> **User Action**
>
> The Project Creation Wizard was not able to connect to
>   the Team Foundation Server \. The reason for the failed connection cannot be
>   determined at this time.

The server is accessible and am able to work with my earlier created Team Project, but not able to create a new one as it tries to look at the `servername\projectcollectionname` instance as the server name. Can someone help to resolve this.

Tried searching the error number and the log related solutions and other forums but could not get any specifics related to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is in the log files? Do you have SharePoint or SSRS configured? And are those configurations still valid?

Comment: Hi Ewald, yes sharepoint and ssrs configured by TFS installer no other specific changes. I did a complete re-install and then tried again to create the Team Project but it didn't work. Same Error.

Comment: I added another colleague as an administrator and then tried creating it from VS IDE on his machine and it allowed to create. So narrowed down to the point that its not working from my machine which it worked i.e. had created Team Project priorly before switch happened to the new server, and yet am able to connect and see the new Team Projects which were added from my colleagues machine but not able to create it from mymachine with this error popping up.

Comment: Log File Error - Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30162: Task "WITs" from Group "WorkItemTracking" failed
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: TF24023: Team Foundation Server Configuration Failure. The New Team Project Wizard work item component could not connect to the Team Foundation Server Dev1\Project1
Exception Details: Contact the administrator for the Team Foundation Server Dev1\Project1 to confirm that the server 
is available on the network.

Comment: Looking at the log files, during the creation of the team project the connection to the server is broken. If the problem is reproducable you can consider to file an incident at https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio